# Почему не открывается svg рисунок из другого файла?

Tags: svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink=" http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink "
xmlns:svg=" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg "
xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg " width="500" height="500">

<use xlink:href="3_.svg#picture3" x="0" y="0" />

</svg>
```

Что я делаю не так? код из самого файла 3_.svg
https://pastebin.com/xsECQQNn
все файлы лежат в одной папке

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: попробовал, все так же

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, а также каким образом вы открываете этот SVG. Как отдельный файл в браузере или что. Добавьте все необходимые детали. Попробуйте включить этот фрагмент в HTML и проверьте работает ли ссылка.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте простую и надежную технику с размещением кода исходного файла в HTML с указанием `width="0"` и `height="0"` в шапке svg файла. Это позволит вам спрятать исходный файл и он не будет занимать место при вёрстке.

Далее его можно использовать по всему HTML документу многократно, увеличивая, уменьшая, позиционируя с помощью такой конструкции

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >  
   Использование копии файла размером 100x100px
<use xlink:href="#picture3"  /> 
 </svg>
```

Копии исходного файла будут вести себя при верстке, как обычные блоки

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >
      
    <g id="picture3">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="376" width="500" style="fill:rgb(66,72,60)"/>
 
    <circle cx="380" cy="120" r="80" style="fill:rgb(122,121,77);"/>
    <circle cx="380" cy="120" r="55" style="fill:rgb(179,170,95);"/>
    <circle cx="380" cy="120" r="30" style="fill:rgb(232,218,111);"/>
 
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(214,142,83);" points="0,195 95,100 371,376 0,376"/>
    <polyline style="fill:rgb(68,46,25);" points="0,195 90,120 295,376 0,376 0,195"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(107,76,48);" points="0,376 90,120 295,376 245,376 165,275 165,376
    90,376 75,290 40,376 0,376 "/>
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" x="0" y="376" height="124" width="500"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(129,123,75);" x="0" y="376" height="24" width="500"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="0" y="376" height="8" width="500"/>
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" x="50" y="0" height="376" width="12"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="62" y="0" height="376" width="3"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="50,146 17,113 50,143"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="50,143 17,113 50,140"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="65,93 65,85 126,26"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="65,86 65,82 126,26"/>
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" x="100" y="0" height="376" width="8"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="108" y="0" height="376" width="3"/>
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" x="190" y="0" height="376" width="25"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="215" y="0" height="376" width="4"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="190,50 140,0 134,0 190,65"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="190,50 140,0 143,0"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="190,173 136,120 190,180"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="190,173 136,120 190,168"/>
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" x="235" y="0" height="376" width="10"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="245" y="0" height="376" width="3"/>
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" x="320" y="0" height="376" width="10"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="330" y="0" height="376" width="3"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="320,175 268,127 320,182"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="320,175 268,127 320,169"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="320,62 296,40 320,65"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="320,62 296,40 320,59"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="333,246 382,200 333,253"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="333,246 382,200 333,241"/>
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" x="390" y="0" height="376" width="6"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="396" y="0" height="376" width="3"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="390,65 352,31 390,70"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="390,65 352,31 390,61"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="399,207 427,179 399,211"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="399,207 427,179 399,203"/>
 
 
    <rect style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" x="460" y="0" height="376" width="30"/>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" x="456" y="0" height="376" width="4"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="456,80 409,32 456,85"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="456,80 409,32 456,73"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(25,30,24);" points="456,267 415,227 456,273"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(197,178,101);" points="456,267 415,227 456,263"/>
 
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" points="25,400 50,376 65,376 40,402"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" points="75,402 100,376 111,376 87,402"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" points="170,402 190,376 219,376 200,402"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" points="212,402 235,376 248,376 226,402"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" points="306,402 320,376 333,376 321,402"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" points="388,402 390,376 399,376 398,402"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(28,30,25);" points="472,402 456,376 490,376 500,392 500,402"/>
 
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(232,218,111);" points="276,61 280,60 282,56 284,60 288,61 284,63 282,67 280,63 276,61"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(232,218,111);" points="262,30 266,29 268,25 269,29 273,30 269,32 268,35 266,32"/>
    <polygon style="fill:rgb(232,218,111);" points="265,90 267,89 268,87 269,89 271,90 269,91 268,93 267,91"/>
    </g>
</svg>


  <div  >
  <span >sssssss</span>
  <span style="display:block">wwwwww</span>
  <span >zzzzzzz</span>
  </div>
  
  <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >  
   <use xlink:href="#picture3"  /> 
 </svg> 
 
 <svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >  
   <use xlink:href="#picture3"  /> 
 </svg> 
 
 <div>rrrrccccccccccccccccccccczzz</div>
 <svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >  
   <use xlink:href="#picture3"  /> 
 </svg> 
 
  <div>uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu</div>
 <svg  viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >  
   <use xlink:href="#picture3"  /> 
 </svg>
```